# What is causing the "does not have Release file" after executing sudo apt-get update?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
I get this message after running the "apt-get update" command:

Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [918 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/twodopeshaggy/jarun/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I ran "sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean" prior to running the previous command.

Fred

I am expecting no error messages.